# How to use setState without using onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and i want to `setState`  a variable that will use to display an `on` and `off` icon. onPressed cannot be used because the input `switch` is a string.

```
void _toggleIcon() {
  setState(() {
      if (switch.contains('on')) {
        _iconState = true;
      } else if (switch.contains('off')) {
        _iconState = false;
      }
  });
}
```

I know that i can use the void function above on `IconButton` on `onPressed` using this code:

```
Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child: IconButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            icon: (_iconState 
                ? const Icon(Icons.star)
                : const Icon(Icons.star_border)),
            color: Colors.red[500],
            onPressed: _toggleIcon,
          ),
        ),
```

But i don't know how to implement it because the input is a string.

I don't also know how to implement a `Icon Class` or is it even possible.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you include where you are using `_toggleIcon`?

Comment: I edit my question. I want to use it on `Icon Class` or `IconButton Class` whichever is possible.

Comment: Please add more details to the question, what is `switch`? is it a `TextEditingController` or `String`?

Comment: `switch` is a string.

Comment: `onPressed` is being used here. You like to change `_iconState`  based on `switch` string, where you are updating this `switch` value.

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh I only know  how to  use `setState` on `onPressed`. Yes, I like to change `_iconState` based on `switch` string. I am updating the `switch` from arduino that sending strings.

Comment: In that case, while receiving string, you can change `_iconState`. Can you update the question to include these details?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ValueNotifier` with `ValueListenableBuilder`.

```dart
ValueNotifier<String> switchString = ValueNotifier("");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
          valueListenable: switchString,
          builder: (context, _iconState, child) {
            return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              child: IconButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                icon: (switchString.value.contains('on')
                    ? const Icon(Icons.star)
                    : const Icon(Icons.star_border)),
                color: Colors.red[500],
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        TextField(
          onChanged: (v) {
            switchString.value = v;
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: How can I input the last string to the text field from this List `final List<String> led = messages.map((_message) => _message.text).toList();` this is list is initialize after build context

Comment: use  `led.last;`

Comment: Where will i put `led.last`?

Comment: it is not clear to me. As for getting last text element, you need  use `list.last`

Comment: Yes, but where in the code I will put it?

Comment: you may want it inside textFiled therefore  put inside `ValueNotifier(list.last)`

Comment: But the list `led` is initialize after build context. Also it will give an output after the bluetooth connection is established and flutter app ask to arduino for input